# How to compare current edited time vs. specified criteria time in an IF Statement in Google Apps Script/Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Goal:**
Insert the current date or tomorrow's date to a cell under Column K/Row of user edit, depending on when the user changes a cell under Column D to "Chat => Email." And if possible, I want the comparison and output of the date to be based on the JST (Japan Standard Time) time zone.

**Context of my code:**
In my below code, I've created a function called "insertDeadlineDate()" which receives onEdit() information from another .gs file. Within the insertDeadlineDate() code, I'm trying to create an if statement to check the following points and execute the result.

1. If the user changed the cell value to "Chat => Email" AND if the current time is between 9:30 A.M. and 2:00 P.M. (JST), then insert the current day's date to Column K/Row of user edit.
2. If the user changed the cell value to "Chat => Email" AND if the current time is between 2:00 P.M. and 6:30 P.M. (JST), then insert the current day's date to Column K/Row of user edit.

FYI: I have the IF statements blank because I don't know what to write. I'm sorry...

```html
function insertDeadlineDate(range, sheetName, row, column) {
  const statusSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Status');
  const editedRangeValue = range.getValue();
  
  // Column numbers for Status sheet
  const caseTypeColumnStatus = 4;

  if (sheetName == 'Status' && column == ticketTypeColumnStatus && row > 15 && editedRangeValue == 'Chat => Email') {
    var statusColumn = column + 3;
    if () { // If the current time is between 9:30 A.M. and 2:00 P.M. (JST), then TRUE. 
      // Insert today's date
      statusSheet.getRange(row, statusColumn).setValue(new Date());
    } else if () { // If the current time is between 2:00 P.M. and 6:30 P.M. (JST), then TRUE.
      // Insert tomorrow's date
      statusSheet.getRange(row, statusColumn).setValue();
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Sheet Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify the scenario, what should happen if the current time is between 6:30 PM (JST) and 9:30 AM - or can that scenario for your script never occur?

Comment: Thanks for the question here!! So if the current time is between 6:30 PM to 9:30 AM, then I'd prefer the script to do nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made some adjustments since I am not passing any parameter, this is `onEdit` directly.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  const sheetName = 'Status';
  const statusSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const cell = statusSheet.getActiveCell();
  const row = cell.getRow();
  const column = cell.getColumn();
  const editedRangeValue = cell.getValue();

  // var currentDate = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Japan' }));

  // The above line of code translates your time into japan timezone but since 
  // sheets is converting your timezone automatically to the regional one, 
  // it adjusts an additional day when used. Be careful in using the above line.

  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Use the line below to test different time slots, we do not want to wait the 
  // exact time just to test this script.
  // currentDate.setHours(11, 30, 0 ,0);

  startDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  startDate.setHours(9, 30, 0, 0);

  endDate1 = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  endDate1.setHours(14, 0, 0, 0);

  endDate2 = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  endDate2.setHours(18, 30, 0, 0);

  // Column numbers for Status sheet
  const caseTypeColumnStatus = 4;

  if (sheetName == 'Status' && column == caseTypeColumnStatus && row > 15 && editedRangeValue == 'Chat => Email') {
    var statusColumn = column + 3;
    if (startDate <= currentDate && endDate1 > currentDate) { // If the current time is between 9:30 A.M. and 2:00 P.M. (JST), then TRUE. 
      // Insert today's date
      statusSheet.getRange(row, statusColumn).setValue(currentDate);
    } else if (endDate1 <= currentDate && endDate2 > currentDate) { // If the current time is between 2:00 P.M. and 6:30 P.M. (JST), then TRUE.
      // Insert tomorrow's date
      var tomorrow = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1));
      if(tomorrow.getDay() == 6){ 
        // if saturday, add 2 days 
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
      } 
      else if(tomorrow.getDay() == 0){
        // if sunday, add 1 day
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
      } 
      statusSheet.getRange(row, statusColumn).setValue(tomorrow);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, @nazia!! This worked! But I have one issue that I didn't realize. Would you be able to help how to add working days? So for example, if the user sets the value to "Chat => Email" on a Friday between the time of 2:00 PM and 6:30 PM, I would prefer set the date that's a working day and avoid adding days that are on weekends or bank holidays. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi @JohnT. , what holidays are we basing the dates? I can assure you we can skip the weekends, but i'll try with holidays

Comment: Hi @NaziA, much appreciation for the response. The holidays are based on the Japan's bank holidays (https://www.google.com/search?q=holidays+in+japan&rlz=1C1GCEA_enJP865JP866&oq=holidays+in+japan&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i457j0l2j69i65j69i60l3.3486j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but if we can't do it, weekends would be fine.
If this is something that I should ask separately, please do let me know and I'll do that.

Comment: Updated the answer @JohnT., can you test the modified part? it should be the last condition when you insert tomorrow's date. as for the holiday, kindly post it in another question since I'm still not sure how to approach the holiday and might need some time. Other users might be able to help you asap you posted the issue. Don't forget to add `google-apps-script` as tag so I can find it easier

Comment: Hi @NaziA! That was super quick. How did you become so knowledgeable..... Anyways, it worked, so thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnT. Haha. I was able to ready it before you asked, forgot to add it previously though. As for the holiday, don't forget to post it in another question with tag `google-apps-script`. I'll try to monitor your next question here.

Comment: I wish there was a way to like assign the question to you. But I'll make sure to ask the question with `google-apps-script` tag. Again, sincerely appreciate your quick and detailed support!